# Firebase Messaging

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-mediaplayer

My question is simple, when I receive push notification from firebase into android app I play sound with loop, but I am stuck that when I click notification. I want to stop playing sound that's it. Here is my code :

```
 Uri alarmSound = Uri.parse(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE
                + "://" + mContext.getPackageName() + "/raw/notification");

        mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(mContext, alarmSound);
        final AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        if (audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING) != 0) {
            mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_RING);
            mMediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
            mMediaPlayer.prepare();
            mMediaPlayer.start();
```

And here is my firebase Messaging Service Code :

```
  public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    Log.e(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());
    if (remoteMessage == null)
        return;
    // Check if message contains a notification payload.
    if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        handleNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
    }
    // Check if message contains a data payload.
    if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Data Payload: " + remoteMessage.getData().toString());
        try {
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(remoteMessage.getData().toString());
            handleDataMessage(json);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}

 private void handleNotification(String message) {
    if (!NotificationUtils.isAppIsInBackground(getApplicationContext())) {
        // app is in foreground, broadcast the push message
        Intent pushNotification = new Intent(Config.PUSH_NOTIFICATION);
        pushNotification.putExtra("message", message);
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(pushNotification);
        // play notification sound
        NotificationUtils notificationUtils = new NotificationUtils(getApplicationContext());
        notificationUtils.playNotificationSound();
    }else{
        // If the app is in background, firebase itself handles the notification
    }
}
private void handleDataMessage(JSONObject json) {
    Log.e(TAG, "push json: " + json.toString());
    try {
        JSONObject data = json.getJSONObject("data");
        Log.e("Khan",data.toString());
        if (!NotificationUtils.isAppIsInBackground(getApplicationContext())) {
            // app is in foreground, broadcast the push message
            Intent pushNotification = new Intent(Config.PUSH_NOTIFICATION);
            pushNotification.putExtra("message", "Testing");
            Log.e("Forground","Testing");
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(pushNotification);
            GcmBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(pushNotification);
            // play notification sound
            NotificationUtils notificationUtils = new NotificationUtils(getApplicationContext());
            notificationUtils.playNotificationSound();
            mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) this
                    .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            Intent in = new Intent(this, ReportActivity.class);
            in.putExtra("check","main");
            Log.e("Clicked","yes");
            PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT, in, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            int numMessages = 0;
            NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                    this).setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
                    getResources(), R.drawable.ic_notifications_active_black_24dp)).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notifications_active_black_24dp)
                    .setContentTitle("RESCUE 15 CCPO Notification")
                    .setSound(Settings.System.DEFAULT_NOTIFICATION_URI)
                    .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText("Testing"))
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setContentText("RESCUE 15 CCPO")
                    .setNumber(++numMessages);
            mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
            mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
        } else {
            // app is in background, show the notification in notification tray
            Intent resultIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ReportActivity.class);
            resultIntent.putExtra("check","noti");
            Log.e("Background","Testing");

            // check for image attachment
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty("Testing")) {
                showNotificationMessage(getApplicationContext(), "Testing", "Testing", "Testing", resultIntent);
            } else {
                // image is present, show notification with image
                showNotificationMessageWithBigImage(getApplicationContext(), "Testing", "Testing", "Testing", resultIntent, "Testing");
            }
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Json Exception: " + e.getMessage());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Exception: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

I hope my question is simple to understand thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

add this to your code ...

```
notification.flags=Notification.FLAG_INSISTENT|Notification.FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS|Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR;
```

under ...

```
 PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT, in, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Comment: Thank you for replay but what is function of this line?

Comment: "notification.flags" what is that variable?